# Read data from .env file on Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm looking for a way to read data from an .env file trough the build process of an image thus option docker-compose is not option as I am using AWS CDK and with "cdk deploy" command the building process initiates same way as running "docker build" command and as far as I see there is not such an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine this will work similarly. I wanted to do the same thing for React and found this article, which helped. The env.sh file in there would be copied to your Dockerfile along with the .env file.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/